# Azure API Management - Versioning

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

We are currently having all our APIs in Azure API Management Portal. The versioning in the API code is handled using the version header. These APIs were deployed into our Production environment mid of Last year. I guess we did not have the versioning concept in the Old API Management Portal and the vendors who are using the APIs which are in Production works without passing the version header (if the version header is not passed, it will fallback to the initial version).

We could see that, currently API Management does have ability to create versions. But, if I create a new version for the existing API – I could see that the existing version (which currently works with or without version header) stops working. It is giving resource not found error. If we go into the API settings page for the Existing version, we could see that the Version Header field is mandatory and not filled.

Is there any way we can default the version header to the initial version through API Management?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but probably worth answering for someone asking in the future.

You can set a header on all API operations in the Azure portal.

Select the API version and then ensure **All operations** is selected in the list of operations.

[image: Select]

Then in the Inbound Processing section click **+ Add policy**.

[image: addpolicy]

Set headers is one of the options.

[image]

Select that and add the details for the header.

[image]

Save and repeat for the other versions you have defined, obviously setting the correct version each time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may also define passing the version as a header parameter when initially adding the API to API Management as Open API Specification Full definition and then set the Header definition in Versioning scheme.[image]